# Create relationships in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationships

I have a graph with about 800k nodes and I want to create random relationships among them, using Cypher.

Examples like the following didn't work because the cartesian product is too big:

```
match (u),(p)
with u,p
create (u)-[:LINKS]->(p);
```

For example I want 1 relationship for each node (800k), or 10 relationships for each node (8M).

In short, I need a query Cypher in order to UNIFORMLY create relationships between nodes.
Does someone know the query to create relationships in this way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write a Cypher query to CREATE links between random nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621407/write-a-cypher-query-to-create-links-between-random-nodes)

Comment: No, the solution proposed falls back into the not working example I wrote in my question.

Answer (score 0):

So you want every node to have exactly `x` relationships? Try this in batches until no more relationships are updated:

```
MATCH (u),(p) WHERE size((u)-[:LINKS]->(p)) < {x}
WITH u,p LIMIT 10000 WHERE rand() < 0.2 // LIMIT to 10000 then sample
CREATE (u)-[:LINKS]->(p)
```

Comment: Why do you LIMIT u,p to 10000 if the nodes are 800k? and why do you sample with rand() at 20%?

Comment: It doesn't work because it creates a lot of relationships for each node.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (assuming your neo4j server has enough memory):

```
MATCH (n)
WITH COLLECT(n) AS ns, COUNT(n) AS len
FOREACH (i IN RANGE(1, {numLinks}) |
  FOREACH (x IN ns |
    FOREACH(y IN [ns[TOINT(RAND()*len)]] |
      CREATE (x)-[:LINK]->(y) )));
```

This query collects all nodes, and uses nested loops to do the following `{numLinks}` times: create a `LINK` relationship between every node and a randomly chosen node.

The innermost `FOREACH` is used as a workaround for the current Cypher limitation that you cannot put an operation that returns a node inside a node pattern. To be specific, this is illegal: `CREATE (x)-[:LINK]->(ns[TOINT(RAND()*len)])`.